# Multiple tags in the cucumber 3.0.1 doesnt run the scenarios

Tags: cucumberjs

Multiple tags in the cucumber 3.0.1 doesn't run the scenarios.

I have two different tags, tagged to two different scenarios under the same feature file. I try to run both the scenarios that are tagged, using the cucumber tags command

cucumber-js --tags=@Smoke,@Regression

When I run this, cucumber doesn't recognize the scenarios, it provides the output like
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s

But when I run the tags individually, like cucumber-js --tags=@Smoke the cucumber is able to recognize and runs the scenario. Any idea why?

It used to work until I upgraded to the latest version of cucumber 3.0.1 and it stopped working

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use and & or conditions for tags. Please make rephrase your tags input as follows:

```
cucumberjs --tags='@Smoke or @Regression'
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add a comment to the above answer, I'm in a windows environment and the need to use double quotes to the above. ie:

```
cucumberjs --tags="@Smoke or @Regression"
```